# Best way to handle https, http, www, and no www with Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a website that I'd like to track properly with Google Analytic. The main site is just `example.com`. There is also a store setup, so we are using `https` on part of the site. My question is: Do I create different profiles for each variation of the domain name? If yes, do I embed all four of them one after another?

URL combinations we have:

```
http://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't see why this question was downvoted, it is something I hear very often from users who are new to Analytics and exactly the kind of thing StackOverflow was designed to help with...upvoting to bring score up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to keep separate URLs, setup cross-domain tracking, ***[using this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite?csw=1)***.

- Setup a master profile, with no filters.
- Setup a cross-domain profile, per above.

Generally no, you don't want different profiles for each of them, as you won't be able to then measure traffic thru the entire site. Each profile is it's own discrete view of the data. If you create separate profiles you won't be able to report off a single, contiguous session on your site.

Also, it's a good practice to setup your web server to always redirect to the main URL that has the certificate... in your case have MySiteExample.com redirect to www.MySiteExample.com.

Finally, this kind of question is actually better asked here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

---

EDIT:

To clarify on the http and https, you don't need to do anything in the property / profile configuration, since they are the same domain. Further, the script that you include for Google Analytics handles avoiding mixed mode (https and http on the page). See this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/#quickstart. Specifically, the following javascript line handles delivering the script via https or http, depending on whether the page was retrieved via http or https. In processing, google analytics doesn't care if you are using https or http.

```
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. I think I mistyped when I said "Profile" I meant "Property"

Comment: Well, normally that would be unfortunate -- and I would have wasted some time helping... ;)  However, in this case, the same answer still applies for the same reasons. Property is actually further up the food chain than profiles (which are now called views). You'll want to aggregate all the traffic to the various URLs as one, since they are really just the same site at different URLs. This means you want one Property. This allows you to to/from HTTP and HTTPs and with and without 'www' and track the entire visit as a single session (and return visits from different links).

Comment: @ChristinaRule -- haven't seen any response regarding the answer.

Comment: thank you so much for all the time you've taken to help me. I'm still having issues understanding what I am suppose to setup for https and just normal http. @RobM

Comment: there is nothing different you need to do for https and http to the same domain. That is covered by the script that you include on the page. See the edit in the answer to further clarify.

Comment: Thanks for this info. It still baffles me because the creation of the property explicitly requires you to specify http or https and appears to generate specific tracking-ids for each. But, if I understand this answer, I needn't worry about this and I will see the aggregate for both?